# Access property of attribute in method

Tags: c#, attributes

I've been looking around to find 'script' to help me to access properties set at runtime from an attribute on a method. I implemented something, but properties set at runtime have only their default value. Is this even possible? I show you the code I have:

First if all, i have an interface:

```
public interface IRootController{}
```

My Controller inherits from a base controller who implements this interface.
In this controller i have a method with an attribute:

```
[LowerAndUpperDateTime]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllLastResponding(string cultureinfo, Guid campaignUniqueID, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string lowerDateTime, string upperDateTime, BreakDown breakDown)
{
    var test = this.GetAttribute<LowerAndUpperDateTimeAttribute>(GetCurrentMethod());
    return null;

}
```

The code of the attribute is like this:

```
public class LowerAndUpperDateTimeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public DateTime UpperDateTime;
        public DateTime LowerDateTime;
        public string test = "sfsdfdsf";
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            if (actionContext.ActionArguments.Count < 1)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    new[]{Errors.ObjectRequired});
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {

                    var lowerDateTime = string.Empty;
                    var upperDateTime = string.Empty;

                    //controleren of de arguments bestaan
                    if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("lowerDateTime"))
                        lowerDateTime = actionContext.ActionArguments["lowerDateTime"].ToString();
                    if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("upperDateTime"))
                        upperDateTime = actionContext.ActionArguments["upperDateTime"].ToString();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lowerDateTime) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(upperDateTime))
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                            new[]{Errors.EmptyDateTimes});
                    }
                    else{

                        try
                        {
                            LowerDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lowerDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            UpperDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(upperDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            if (LowerDateTime > UpperDateTime)
                                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                                    new[]{Errors.LowerDateBiggerTheUpperDate});
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                            new[]{e.Message});
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new[]{Errors.NoAccess});
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

The extensionmethod i created that is used in the method of my controller to access the attribute looks like this:

```
public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this IRootController currentclass, string methodname)where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    return (TAttribute)currentclass.GetType().GetMethod(methodname).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So this way i can access the attribute, but both datetimes have the defaultvalues, even when they got set.

Is it even possible what i'm trying here and if so, where am i wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine here. Are you using `.net 4.5`? If so, this one liner does it all for you: `var att = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetCustomAttribute<LowerAndUpperDateTimeAttribute>();` You only need to add `using System.Reflection;` I suspect you are using 4.5, because I assume `GetCurrentMethod` uses `[CallerMemberName]`.

Comment: So you do get a value other then 1/01/0001 0:00:00? Indeed, we are using 4.5. I added System.Reflection everywhere now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, I am sorry. That is always the default, because all methods are invoked at runtime by the framework it self. Therefore the given method is never invoked if you 'just' retrieve the attribute manually. Can you please explain what your ultimate end goal is?

Comment: Ah ok, that's too bad. I have a lot of methods who need a lowerdate (string) and upperdate( string) as parameters. It's also a lot of repetative code, to convert those strings to datetimes. So i thought to solve this with this attribute. It looked nice and clean :)